# Is the phrase "observations that are resulted from" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I have three project stages and the third one will be based on the last two stages. For this, is the following sentence correct:

> This stage will include applying improvements to the test generation process based on the observations that are resulted from the last two stages.

My concern is with `observations that are resulted from`. Is it correct?

Comment: The verb ‘to result’ is transitive.  It does not have a passive voice.  So ‘is resulted from’ is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase it as:

> ... the observations that result from ...

It's simpler and, I think, flows better.  [Google's Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%20are%20resulted%20from%2C%20that%20result%20from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20are%20resulted%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20result%20from%3B%2Cc0) suggests that your original phrasing (*that are resulted from*) is far less common than the simpler form (*that result from*).

A better way of writing this, in my opinion, would be:

> ... *based on the observations **made in** the **previous** two stages.*

However, technically, general proofreading and writing advice are off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think there is a better way to re-write the sentence?

Comment: @AdamAmin This answer more than addresses your specific concern. As stated, anything else in terms of rewriting would fall under proofreading, which is off topic.